# The use of "contact someone with something"

Tags: word-usage, complements, collocations

> With these facts, Katia figures out that her dad would be living in a
>   country which has a warm climate where orchids can grow, has Tamil as
>   one of its official languages and where advanced medical treatments
>   are available. Just as she is about to determine the country, 47
>   bursts through the door, shoots Smith in the chest, and knocks Katia
>   unconscious. Elsewhere, 47's handler Diana **contacts** another Agent
>   **with** a contract.
>
> [Plot: Hitman: Agent 47](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hitman:_Agent_47)

The use of "contact someone with a contract" sounds a bit unconventional to me.

We can provide / supply / present someone with something, as is exemplified by the online dictionaries. But the dictionaries don't include the collocation of "contact someone with something".

Without any context, I think there would be an ambiguity in "A contacted B with a contract". It could mean "A had a contract and contacted B", or "A contacted B to award B a contract". Do I get it right?

In the quoted example, I think "with a contract" acts as the object complement.

Then let's generalize this use:

> A visited / approached / ran to / notified / engaged B with a contract.

Do they sound natural to a native speaker's ear?

Comment: The sentence is ambiguous, though context suggests that it probably has your last suggested meaning. ... By and large I think this sort of writing is not a good source of useful questions. Even if it is well written, it reflects "translation" from a medium and a genre in which much is deliberately left unspoken and suggestive to enhance narrative tension, and that ambiguity tends to slop over into the translation.

Comment: @StoneyB +1 Quite correct, but as a non-native speaker he may not realise that...

Comment: Yes, I agree. Without watching the movie even a native speaker might fail to understand the over-condensed plot summary. After reading both of your comments I think I can make my question more specific. @StoneyB, Peter

Comment: @Peter ... Indeed! But KinzleB has a sharper eye for slovenly writing than 99% of native speakers.

Comment: You have to read the sentence as "Diana contacts another Agent who is with a contract" or "Diana contacts another Agent who has a contract".

Comment: @StoneyB Being <1% of a general population is usually considered a **gift** :)

Comment: No, I don't think so. The Agent hasn't gotten the contract until Diana contacts him. Your interpretation would let one think he has already been contracted! ! @Rathony

Comment: @Peter ... Yes; and I consider KinzleB a gifted reader and questioner.

Comment: The verb contact doesn't carry any prepositional or object complement. The context seems to be "Diana has a contract with another killer (agent) to kill 47. After 47 accomplishes his/her mission, Diana needs to get rid of 47. Then, Dinana contacts another killer to kill 47.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is ambiguity in your isolated phrase

> A **contacted** B **with** a contract

the possibilities are

> Is A merely contacting B and one of them has a contract?
>   Does A have the contract?
>   Does B have the contract?
>   Does A have the contract with the intent of giving it to B after contacting B?

By the **Law of Proximity**(1)

> A contacted B with a contract *(B has the contract)*
>   With a contract, A contacted B *(A has the contract)*

Because of **context** from your passage

> A *(has a contract and has)* contacted B with *(said)* contract *(to give to B)*

since A is B's **handler** and **handlers** do not phone-in for updates, they wait to be notified (minimal communication)

In your example question

> A visited / approached / ran to / notified / engaged B with a contract.

Let's try this

> John **visited** Jane with flowers
>   John **visited** Jane with Sally

I think most people would interpret it as the flowers and Sally were with John

> John **approached** Jane with Sally
>   John **ran to** Jane with Sally
>   John **notified** Jane with Sally

would also be interpreted as Sally being with John

change **with** to **and** and any ambiguity disappears

> John **approached** Jane and Sally
>   John **ran to** Jane and Sally
>   John **notified** Jane and Sally

however

> John **saw** Jane **with** Sally

would usually be interpreted as Jane and Sally were together.

(1) this may not be a **real** law, but is usually understood

Comment: I didn't ask about the semantics of the quoted example. Perhaps I didn't make myself understood. :(

Comment: @KinzleB Sorry, What is it you want to know? Please give an additional example if you can. Was your question about the ambiguity you perceive? Who has what?

Comment: @KinzleB I have reedited my answer, it that closer to what you're asking?

Comment: @Peter I can't resist comparing "John visited Jane with flowers" to "YHWH visited Pharaoh with plagues."

Comment: @StoneyB I think Peter nailed it. +1) Law of Proximity should be applied here. Otherwise, the writer should not use that construction. The sentence seems to be ambiguous but it is not difficult to write "Diana contacts another agent to reward (give) a (new) contract...".

Comment: @StoneyB +1 An excellent example of usage of **visited** and **with**. That is beyond **native**, it is an example of being **well-spoken** (written). **ELL readers take note**

Comment: @Peter Wouldn't it be better to use the preposition **for** instead of **with** if the Diana's intention was to give a contract by contacting the agent? **With flower** and **with plagues** sound natural because the subjects represent the obvious. If we contrast "I contacted the department for information", with "I contacted the dept. with information", the distinction seems to be clearer.

Comment: @Ranthony **I contacted the dept. for info** the dept has info that you want. **I contacted the dept with info** you have info to give the dept. "I contacted **the guy with all the answers**" might mean you need an answer, but **the guy with all the answers** would need to be established in previous context. Diana would never contact the agent **for** the contract, since she is the agent's **handler**, **hit contracts** (like other things) flow one-way. "Diana contacted the agent for a phone num" the agent has the phone num that Diana wants, yes that is unambiguous.

Comment: @Rathony "Diana was contacted by another agent with a contract" is also unambiguous, the agent has the contract

Comment: BTW, does "A visited / approached / ran to / called B with a contract" sound natural?

Comment: @KinzleB They are all possible, just more context is needed. "**A** visited **B** with a contract at their offices." though "**A** paid a visit to **B** with a contract" would sound better. "**A** approached **B** with a contract for next season." "**A** ran to **B** with a contract before the transfer window closed." "**A** called **B** with a contract."

Answer (score 1):

I take the probable meaning of *with a contract* to be "in order to award/assign him a contract"; but although B is presumably going to end up "with the contract", *object complement* seems to me to be stretching the sense of that term here. *With a contract* does not describe B, or even A; it describes the intention behind the action *contact*.

I would characterize *with a contract* as a clausal adjunct—in traditional terms, an "adverbial of purpose".

Comment: I have a little difficulty pinpointing my bewilderment. Perhaps my intention was to compare "provide sb with sth" with "contact sb with sth". I thought they had different syntactic structures...

Comment: @KinzleB as in "**contact** sb with **sth** to provide **the sth** to the contactee"?  He contacted me with information. He provided me with information.  In order to **provide** one must make **contact**, but not vice versa

Comment: @KinzleB There is no difference in the syntax. The difference lies in the lexical relationships: *provide/supply/furnish/present* "select" *with X* for a specific sense, but other verbs don't have this pre-programmed sense. If you have *CGEL*, this is treated at Ch 4, 6.1.1 on page 275, 'specified and unspecified prepositions'.

Comment: I looked up 'clausal adjunct' in CGEL and Bas Aarts; Both returned nothing. I would have thought that a clause would have at least a verb in it. Why would you call a PP 'with a contract' a clausal adjunct? Does it mean 'an adjunct which is a clause' or 'an adjunct modifying a clause'?

Comment: @KinzleB I mean an adjunct modifying a clause. You're quite right, this is just the sort of confusing terminology I need to find a better way of expressing -- perhaps 'adclausal (adjunct)', like 'adverbal' or 'adnominal'.